# Custom keyboard that mimics the default iOS "globe" button

Tags: ios

In iOS keyboards there is a globe button that if held will show a pop-up list of keyboards that the user can switch to.

However in the `KeyboardViewController` class, the only method I see to make a keyboard switch button is the method:

```
        self.advanceToNextInputMode()
```

The problem with this is that while it allows you to create a button that if clicked will switch keyboards this method does not allow you to create a button that if you press and hold will show the list of currently enabled keyboards that the user can switch to by moving their finger to the correct entry.

How can I mimic the default iOS globe keyboard button behavior?

Answer (score 3):

// Launch inputMode list above the view when long pressing or swiping up from the view,

// Advance to nextInputMode when short tapping on the view.

// Example: 
[KeyboardButton addTarget:self action:@selector(handleInputModeListFromView:withEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventAllTouchEvents].

- (void)handleInputModeListFromView:(nonnull UIView *)view withEvent:(nonnull UIEvent *)event **NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(10_0);**

Swift Code

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Perform custom UI setup here
    self.nextKeyboardButton = UIButton(type: .system)

    self.nextKeyboardButton.setTitle(NSLocalizedString("Next Keyboard", comment: "Title for 'Next Keyboard' button"), for: [])
    self.nextKeyboardButton.sizeToFit()
    self.nextKeyboardButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    self.nextKeyboardButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleInputModeList(from:with:)), for: .allTouchEvents)

    self.view.addSubview(self.nextKeyboardButton)

    self.nextKeyboardButton.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    self.nextKeyboardButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
}
```

Comment: Could you write this example in Swift or maybe format it a little bit? Also is this a complete code sample?

Comment: This is a new method that will be available only in iOS 10 and above.